# Contradictory results for ODE in Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, simplifying-expressions

I am Solving the ODE
$$x'(t)=A x(t)+w(t)$$

MMA gives a general result as
$$x(t)\to e^{A t} \int_1^t e^{-A K[1]} w(K[1]) \, dK[1]+c_1 e^{A t}$$

Now I substitute $w(t)$ by $e^{-t}$, and obtain:
$$c_1 e^{A t}+\frac{e^{A t-t} \left(e^{-A}-e^{-A t}\right)}{A}$$

However, If I solve it directly:
$$\text{DSolve}\left[x'(t)=A x(t)+e^{-t},x(t),t\right]$$
I have
$$x(t)\to \frac{e^{A t} \left((A+1) c_1-e^{-(A+1) t}\right)}{A+1}$$
These two approaches give contradictory result since
$$\text{Simplify}\left[c_1 e^{A t}+\frac{e^{A t-t} \left(e^{-A}-e^{-A t}\right)}{A}==\frac{e^{A t} \left((A+1) c_1-e^{-(A+1) t}\right)}{A+1}\right]$$
does not hold true.

This is quite strange because two different approaches should be the same.

Comment: I think you made a mistake in integration $\int_1^t e^{-A\xi} e^{-\xi}d\xi$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the same solution as follows. (btw, even though Mathematica's result is correct, I never liked it shows the integral from $1$ to $t$ and then uses `K[1]` for integration variable, and then adds the constant of integration before that.) It is correct, but strange way of writing it.

When doing as by hand, you could do

```
Clear["Global`*"];
ode = x'[t] == A*x[t] + w[t];
sol = DSolve[ode, x[t], t]
```

[image]

Now make the definite integral indefinite (we can do this, because constant of integration already added by Mathematica.

```
 sol = sol /. {K[1], 1, t} :> K[1] /. K[1] -> t
```

[image]

Now do the replacement you wanted as you did, it will work now

```
 sol = (sol /. w[any_] :> Exp[any])
```

[image]

Now activative

```
 sol1 = Activate[sol] // Simplify
```

[image]

Compare to

```
 ode2 = x'[t] == A*x[t] + Exp[t];
 sol2 = DSolve[ode2, x[t], t] // Simplify
```

[image]

it is the same.

You do not have to do it this way, but the above is how this is solved "by hand" on paper.

The problem you had, is you tried to replace `w[K[1]]` by `Exp[t]` inside the integral, when the integral variable was not $t$ by still `K[1]`

**An alternative way**, if you do not want to change the integral as above, is the following

```
Clear["Global`*"];
ode = x'[t] == A*x[t] + w[t];
sol = DSolve[ode, x[t], t]
```

[image]

```
 sol = (sol /. w[any_] :> Exp[any])
```

[image]

```
  sol1 = Activate[sol] // Expand
```

[image]

Compare to

```
ode2 = x'[t] == A*x[t] + Exp[t];
sol2 = DSolve[ode2, x[t], t] // Simplify
```

[image]

Now you might complain that these two answers do not look the same.

But they are actually exactly the same. This is because the extra term in sol1, which is

$$
-\frac{e^{A t-A+1}}{1-A}
$$

is just a constant multiplied by $e^{At}$, and hence it can be combined with the $e^{At} c_1$ already there, and we get new constant $c_1$ which represents the combinations of these constants into one. That is why Mathematica's answer is correct, when it starts the definite integral from `1` or any other value will work, since this just adds a constant which can always be combined with the constant present.